# Compare phrase from Speech To Text and phrase from IF statement

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm trying to compare phrase getting from TTS and phrase from IF statement. If the phrase from TTS equals to phrase from IF statement it has to appear in TextView. If doesn't, doesn't appear. I try to do this but I have a problem with If statement. It doesn't appear even if the phrases equals or not.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button recognizeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    recognizeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "You may speak!");
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.ENGLISH);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> results;
        results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            TextView speechText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        //if (results.equals("car")) {
            speechText.setText(results.toString());
     //   }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you are comparing an Array of Strings with a String, try something like: `results.get(0).equals("car")`, make sure `results` isn't empty first

Comment: Thank's this works! + to your reputation))

Comment: Great :D I added it as an answer to your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing an Array of Strings with a String, try something like: results.get(0).equals("car"), make sure `results` isn't empty first.

Something like:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> results;
        results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            TextView speechText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        if (results != null && results.size() > 0 && results.get(0).equals("car")) {
            speechText.setText(results.toString());
        }
    }
}
```